# How can I make bookmark bar folders not be tab group icons?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tabs

I like tab groups in Chrome desktop (Windows 10), hence I have chrome://flags/#tab-groups-save enabled.

[image: 'save group' screenshot]

However this means that all top-level bookmark folders on my bookmark bar are now buttons that try to open a whole tab group.  This is IDIOTIC.

[image: 'are you sure you want to open 24 tabs' screenshot]

I know that right-clicking on a tab group button allows me to explore the contents as if it was the old kind of bookmark folder.

[image: right-click tab group to explore contents]

Is there any way to allow me to save tab groups, but not force everything I have saved on the bookmark bar to be a tab group button that tries to open multiple tabs unless right-clicked?

**ETA**: Chrome for Windows Version 99.0.4844.84. (I cannot upgrade to a different version because it is managed by my employer.)

Answer (score 1):

In version 101 folders return to the old behavior and groups are saved independently next to the folders but they disappear when you close the navigator...

In your version you could disable it to return to the old behavior, create specific folders and open it in groups using right click and choosing the tab group option. Not the best solution but is like it is.

I hope they keep improving this, right now it's not very useful, with some changes it would become essential.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll find out when my org is willing to advance to version 101, and I guess I'll disable "save tab groups" for now.